# Get highest value from column in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table:

```
id date  day
2  21-07 1
2  10-07 3
2  11-07 2
```

I need to get `date` which has highest `day`, in current example it should be 10-07.
Next query works fine, but is there way to make it more optimised?

```
SELECT date
      FROM (SELECT date, MAX(day)
            FROM some_table 
            WHERE id = 2
            GROUP BY date
        LIMIT 1) x
```

Comment: It is just a coincidence that your code works.  Here is an example where it does not do what you want:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9fa21c7299821b22ab3484647990965b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not suggest a `where` clause.  Just use:

```
select date
from some_table
where id = 2
order by day desc
limit 1;
```